# R sort by Year then Month in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you look at my ***df_summary_mo*** table it is nicely arranged first by year, then by month.

```
     year month    total
   <fctr> <chr>    <dbl>
 1   2017    10 11.02006
 2   2017    11 16.62367
 3   2017    12 14.84555
 4   2018    01 14.61277
 5   2018    02 14.06558
 6   2018    03 15.73514
 7   2018    04 14.51999
 8   2018    05 14.33848
 9   2018    06 13.49925
10   2018    07 14.04433
11   2018    08  3.88255
```

By default ggplot2 sorts this particular graph (code below) in a format that places the months numerically in order (1,2,3,4...). How do I get the graph to place the 2017 months before the 2018 months? I messed around with the ***reorder*** argument but it doesn't seem to help.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(date = today() + days(1:300), value = runif(300))

df_summary_mo <- df %>%
mutate(year = format(date, "%Y"), month = format(date, "%m")) %>%
group_by(year, month) %>%
summarise(total = sum(value))

ggplot(df_summary_mo, aes(month, total, fill=year, reorder(year,month))) + geom_col()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define `yearmon` so that the order works automatically...

```
df_summary_mo <- df %>%
  mutate(year = format(date, "%Y"), yearmon = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  group_by(year, yearmon) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(value))

ggplot(df_summary_mo, aes(yearmon, total, fill=year)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Adding to the answer given by @AndrewGustar, the x-axis labels can be rotated by using, `element_text()` to the `ggplot()` call, like, `ggplot(df_summary_mo, aes(yearmon, total, fill=year)) + geom_col()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))`. This way, the `x-axis` labels will not overlap.